# Joining two ListViews into one in flutter

Tags: android, ios, listview, flutter

I have to list items in my flutter project and I need them to be viewed one after another using 2 `ListView`, here is more details :

**lists**

```dart
  List<List<theLineModel.Line>> moreThenOneLineList = [];
  List<Station> mutualStationsList = [];
  List<theLineModel.Line> oneLineList = [];
```

**The Widget**

```dart
                           child: Column(
                                  children: <Widget>[
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ListView(
                                        children: oneLineList.map((line) {
                                          return GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {
                                              Navigator.pushNamed(
                                                  context, '/line_details',
                                                  arguments: {
                                                    'line': line,
                                                    'oneLine': true,
                                                  });
                                            },
                                            child: Card(
                                              color: Colors.deepPurple,
                                              elevation: 8,
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                child: Column(
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceEvenly,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${line
                                                              .transportationType}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .center,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${line.startStation
                                                              .stationName}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .center,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Icon(
                                                          Icons.arrow_downward,
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                          size: 30,
                                                        )
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .center,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${line.endStation
                                                              .stationName}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${line.price} ${S
                                                              .of(context)
                                                              .le}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${line.notes}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }).toList(),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: ListView(
                                        children: moreThenOneLineList
                                            .map((lineList) {
                                          return GestureDetector(
                                            onTap: () {},
                                            child: Card(
                                              color: Colors.blueAccent,
                                              elevation: 8,
                                              child: Padding(
                                                padding:
                                                const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                                child: Column(
                                                  children: <Widget>[
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceEvenly,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${lineList[0]
                                                              .transportationType}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .center,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${chosenStations[0]
                                                              .stationName}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .center,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Icon(
                                                          Icons.arrow_downward,
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                          size: 30,
                                                        )
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .center,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${mutualStationsList[moreThenOneLineList
                                                              .indexOf(
                                                              lineList)]
                                                              .stationName}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${lineList[0]
                                                              .price} ${S
                                                              .of(context)
                                                              .le}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${lineList[0]
                                                              .notes}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Icon(
                                                      Icons.arrow_downward,
                                                      color: Colors.white,
                                                      size: 30,
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceEvenly,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${lineList[1]
                                                              .transportationType}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .center,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${mutualStationsList[moreThenOneLineList
                                                              .indexOf(
                                                              lineList)]
                                                              .stationName}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .center,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Icon(
                                                          Icons.arrow_downward,
                                                          color: Colors.white,
                                                          size: 30,
                                                        )
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .center,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${chosenStations[1]
                                                              .stationName}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),
                                                    Row(
                                                      mainAxisAlignment:
                                                      MainAxisAlignment
                                                          .spaceBetween,
                                                      children: <Widget>[
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${lineList[1]
                                                              .price} ${S
                                                              .of(context)
                                                              .le}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                        Text(
                                                          "${lineList[1]
                                                              .notes}",
                                                          style: TextStyle(
                                                              color:
                                                              Colors.white,
                                                              fontSize: 20),
                                                        ),
                                                      ],
                                                    ),

                                                  ],
                                                ),
                                              ),
                                            ),
                                          );
                                        }).toList(),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
```

And then as both lists have been added to a different `ListView` so it caused space and bad looking page at the end, check the image.

[image]

So, any idea how to add both lists to a single Listview?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join two `List`s into a single `ListView` as follow:

```
  Scaffold(
        body: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: ListView(
                children: list1//list1 is a dummy list of String I created for demonstration
                    .map(
                      (listElement) => Text(//return your own widget instead of this
                        listElement,
                        style:
                            TextStyle(fontSize: 40, color: Colors.cyanAccent),
                      ),
                    )
                    .toList()
                      ..addAll(
                        list2.map(//list2 also is a dummy list of String I created for demonstration
                          (listElement) => Text(//return your own widget instead of this
                            listElement,
                            style: TextStyle(
                                fontSize: 40, color: Colors.cyanAccent),
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way to make listview more flexible: [DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/e8c69cdcb0ec833c51a3f0f7bd81bd9e)

Use `...List` to connect multi-list:

```dart
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Demo listview items
    List<String> list1 = [for (int i=0; i < 30;i++) i.toString()];
    List<String> list2 = [for (int i=30; i < 50;i++) i.toString()];
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            Expanded(
            child: ListView(
            children:[
              // Some widgets here
              const Text('List1'),
              // list1 here
              ...list1.map((String text) => Text(text)).toList(),
              // Some widgets between them
              const Text('List2'),
              // list2 here
              ...list2.map((String text) => Text(text)).toList(),
            ],),
            ),
          ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Using the children property of ListView will build all the children at once

Answer (score 1):

Here is the another way to combine two list together and show them in a one `ListView`.

```dart
final List<String> list1 = ['Item 1', 'Item 2', 'Item 3'];
final List<String> list2 = ['Item A', 'Item B', 'Item C'];
    
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Merge two list with one listview"),
  ),
  body: ListView.builder(
    itemCount: list1.length + list2.length,
    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
      if (index < list1.length) {
        return Text(list1[index]);
      } else {
        int lastListIndex = index - list1.length;
        return Text(list2[lastListIndex]);
      }
    },
  ),
);
```